# How do I replace a line in a file using Perl?

Tags: perl

How do I change the contents of a file from this:

```
setenv api1000 Delhi
setenv CODEDROP regular
setenv RELEASETYPE build
setenv CDBUILD CD30
```

To this (replaced string *regular* to *CD29* in second line):

```
setenv api1000 Delhi
setenv CODEDROP CD29
setenv RELEASETYPE build
setenv CDBUILD CD30
```

### My attempt:

```
my $CD_VER = CD29;

open RF, "<$OldFile" or die "Cannot open $OldFile for reading.";
open WF, ">$NewFile" or die "Cannot open $NewFile for writing.";

while ( <RF> ) {
    if (/CODEDROP/){
        if( /regular/) {
            $_ =~ s/regular/$CD_VER/ ;
            print WF "$_";
        }
    }

close RF;
close WF;

copy("$NewFile","$OldFile");  # Both became same
```

The output I am getting as below in the destination file:

```
setenv api1000 Delhi
setenv CODEDROP regular   (I NEED to REMOVE this LINE)
setenv CODEDROP CD29       (only this line should be there)
setenv RELEASETYPE build
setenv CDBUILD CD30
```

Comment: There is [no such thing as PERL](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq1.html#Whats-the-difference-between-perl-and-Perl-)

Comment: Please learn to use the StackOverflow editor. It has helpful buttons for you to mark the parts of your question that are code as code … so they remain readable.

Comment: @Quentin: You have the power to edit.

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the output you claim it does for the input you provided. The code you posted actually does exactly what you want.

Comment: [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only actual problem with your code was that you were printing the line to the new file in the wrong place in the loop. You need to print every line from the old file into the new file.

Having tidied your file a little and updated some of the idioms, I end up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $old_file = 'in.txt';
my $new_file = 'out.txt';

my $CD_VER = 'CD29';

open my $rf, '<', $old_file or die "Cannot open $old_file for reading.";
open my $wf, '>'. $new_file or die "Cannot open $new_file for writing.";

while ( <$rf> ) {
    if (/CODEDROP/ and /regular/) {
        s/regular/$CD_VER/ ;
    }
    print $wf $_;
}

close $rf;
close $wf;
```

Comment: Your entire `if` could be replaced with `s/(\bCODEDROP\s+)regular/$1$CD_VER/`, and it would be a tighter (and therefore less brittle) match to boot.

Comment: @hochgurgler `s/\bCODEDROP\s+\Kregular/$CD_VER/`

Answer (score 2):

If that's all it's doing then you can do it as a one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's:(\bCODEDROP\s+)regular:$1CD29:' oldfile > newfile
```

If you like you can even edit the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's:(\bCODEDROP\s+)regular:$1CD29:' oldfile
```

Comment: It is doing lot of other modifactions Hoch,   only this issue i am not able to fix

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<RF>) {
    if (/CODEDROP\s+regular/) {
        $_ =~ s/regular/$CD_VER/ ;
    }
    print WF "$_";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Crafty,  But still I am getting same output. Still it is printing  the line which has the string "regular".

Comment: @Jeevan It is not possible to duplicate your line with the code you have pasted in your question. You must be printing it twice, or inserting a line twice in the same print statement.