# How to replace one line or one word of a file in Perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a program in Perl. I need to open an existing file and replace only one word in it. So I need to know how to replace a word or a line of a file using Perl.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I know how to open a file and write to it or to append using
open FILE1, ">FileName.txt" or die $!;
print FILE1 "Hello World\n";
close FILE1;

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Comment: The standard way to perform quick changes to a file is to use the `-p` and `-i` command line switches, e.g.: `perl -pi -e 's/^Name:\s*\K.*/New Name/' input.txt`. You can use just `-p` to verify that the changes are correct, and `-pi.bak` to store a backup.

Comment: If you want a Perl program but don't know the language then you have two choices: either learn Perl or engage a programmer who does know Perl. Stack Overflow is a site that helps programmers overcome problems with their code, it isn't a place where you can get software written without paying for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace a line in a file using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230171/how-do-i-replace-a-line-in-a-file-using-perl)

Answer (score 6):

Sure, here's what you need to do:

1. Open the file for reading.
2. Open a temporary file for writing.
3. While you haven't reached the end of the file,

   1. Read a line from the input file.
   2. Use `s///` to change the line.
   3. Print the possibly modified line to the output file.
4. Close both files.
5. `rename` the output file to the input file's name.

Comment: Sorry! as I am a very beginner to Perl, I cannot understand the method you have described

Comment: You need help reading a line from a file? `while (<$fh>)`

Comment: @ikegami you're right, I'm a moron...

Answer (score 1):

first open file using file handler

`open(KI,"$gy"); #$gy contain your file location`

Now after file is opened do this:

```
while(my $line= <KI>)
{
if($_=~'word or pattern to be found')
{
$_=~ s/word_pattern to be changed/new word/;
}
}
```

for e.g:
To replace an occurrence of london by London in the string we can use
s/london/London/

Notice that the two regular expressions (london and London) are surrounded by a total of three slashes. The result of this expression is the number of substitutions made, so it is either 0 (false) or 1 (true) in this case.

If you face any difficulty kindly reply , will be happy to help

Comment: Actually what I need to do is to change a word occurring after a specific word.  e.g. change "Name: John Smith" to "Name: David Beckham". So will this work for me?

Comment: I think it will.. search for name then replace .. if not kindly reply

Comment: this is exactly what you want [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230171/how-do-i-replace-a-line-in-a-file-using-perl?rq=1)

Comment: Things wrong with your `open` statement: Use a lexical file handle, e.g. `my $fh`. Check the return value with `or die $!`. Don't quote the file name needlessly. Use three argument open: `open my $fh, "<", $gy or die $!`. Things wrong with your loop: It is redundant to perform a match before the substitution: The substitution cannot match if the match does not match. You use the variable `$line` in the loop condition, but you perform changes on `$_`. Also, you do not print or store the text anywhere.

Comment: I have to agree with TLP. This information is not wrong, so I won't downvote, but it is terrible practice and should not be mimicked.

Comment: bad practices like that should be obvious shouldn't they? if you look at a lot of examples, they are all bad practices the way they are, the person giving the example would hope the person reading would have enough sense to add that stuff after getting the gist of it. I myself hate examples that add all that stuff which can cloud the example given. If you are going to do that put it in a footnote not in the example if you think the person is to stupid to realize it (like in the 'for dummies' series you see at the bookstore).