# Replace newline followed by foo with bar

Tags: macos, perl, terminal

With Terminal on a Mac, I have in the past used the command  `perl -pi -w -e 's/foo/bar/g;' file` to replace `foo` with `bar` in file. But, I would now like to replace a newline followed by `foo` with `bar`, and `perl -pi -w -e 's/\nfoo/bar/g;' file` does not work (it does nothing, like when it does not find the search string).

As a specific example, the content of file is

```
foo1
foo
```

and I would like to replace it with

```
foo1bar
```

but after I run the above perl command, the file is not changed at all.

I am able to replace the newline by itself, so `perl -pi -w -e 's/\n/bar/g;' file` will work, but I need to replace the newline only if it is followed by `foo`. I have also tried with the `sed` command but without success.

I have the latest version of the Mac OS (Sonoma).

Comment: `perl -p` processes the file line by line, so it can't see a broader context than a single line. Use `-0777` (or `-g` on newer Perls) to process the whole file as a single string.

Comment: Re *"replace a newline followed by foo with bar"*: That can probably be reformulated as matching "foo" in ***the beginning*** of a line (but not by using "\n"). Removing the newline could be by conditional output (not using auto output). There is likely a better duplicate somewhere.

Comment: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890781/how-to-remove-newline-from-the-end-of-a-file-using-perl/66891780#66891780) of conditional output (by manipulating the current line (the buffer)).

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230171/how-do-i-replace-a-line-in-a-file-using-perl/9230700#9230700) may be close (can 'easily' be converted into one-liner form and shortened using the appropriate command line options).

Comment: @PeterMortensen My problem was completely solved by the answer to the duplicate questions. It worked exactly as I wanted at the first attempt. I had posted a  comment to point this out but it was deleted when the question was closed.

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427637/4014959